# Is the integral less than $\frac{n!}2?$

Tags: integration

Knowing that $$\int_0^\infty x^n\exp(-x)\,dx=n!,$$
can we prove the following inequality: $$\int_0^n x^n\exp(-x) \,dx< \frac{n!}2 \;\;?$$

Comment: Why dont you use MathJax and make the reading easy?

Comment: what do you mean by * * exp(-x) ?

Comment: You may want to check out the incomplete gamma function (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), maybe specifically the Special Values section.

Comment: In effect you are asked to prove the right-skewed Gamma distribution has a mean which exceeds its median

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^n\exp(-x)$. Then $f$ has a global maximum at $x=n$.
It suffices to prove that $f(n+h) \ge f(n-h)$ for $0 \le h \le n$.
This reduces to $(n+h)^n \ge e^{2 h} (n - h)^n$ or 
$$
\left(1+\frac{2h}{n-h}\right)^n \ge e^{2h}
$$ but I don't see how to finish it right now.

Comment: The probability distribution
$$
f_n(x)\,dx = \frac{ x^{n-1} e^{-x} \, dx }{(n-1)!} \text{ for } x\ge0 \tag 1
$$
has expected value $n$, as seen by recalling that the expected value is $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx,$ and has variance $n,$ as can be seen by recalling that the variance is the expected value of the square minus the square of the expected value, and also that the expected value of the square is $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty x^2 f(x)\,dx.$

Now notice the convolution$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\qquad (f_n * f_m) = f_{n+m}.$ The probability density function of the sum of independent random variables is the convolution of their densities. Thus $f_n(x)\,dx$ is the distribution of the sum of $n$ independent random variables each distributed as $e^{-x}\,dx.$ Hence the central limit theorem is applicable. Let $X$ be a random variable distributed as $(1).$ Then the distribution of $\dfrac{X-n}{\sqrt n}$ approaches
$$
\frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} \, dx
$$
as $n\to\infty.$ Thus
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^n \frac{x^{n-1} e^{-x} \, dx}{(n-1)!} = \frac 1 2.
$$

Comment: Your proposed integral is $\displaystyle \int_0^{n-1} \frac{x^{n-1} e^{-x} \, dx}{(n-1)!},$ so it's slightly smaller than something that approaches $1/2.$ But that does not prove it's $<1/2$ (if it did I'd have made this an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: The indefinite integral can be calculated.  For large n it is approximately $n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}\approx \frac{n!}{e}\lt\frac{n!}{2}$.

Comment: error in previous comment by self  - ignore

Comment: A direct calculation  is $n!(1-e^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n^k}{k!})=n!e^{-n}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{n^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a step back and think a bit more elementary.

Consider the graph of $f(x) = x^n \exp(-x)$. Flip it over the line $x=n$ to get $f(2n-x)$. It is enough to show that

$$\int_{n}^{2n} f(2n-x) \, dx < \int_{n}^{2n} f(x) \, dx \,.$$

I will now show that if $x \in (n, 2n)$, then $f(2n-x) < f(x)$, which is enough to prove the above. Rearranging,

$$
\begin{align}
(2n-x)^n \exp(x-2n) &< x^n \exp(-x) \\
\left( \frac{2n-x}{x} \right) &< \exp(2(n-x)). 
\end{align}
$$

Now, let's do a little shift to $x \in (0, n)$ by doing $x \mapsto x-n$. Then we need to prove that

$$\left(\frac{n-x}{n+x}\right)^n < \exp(-2x).$$

Take the logarithm of both sides(it is well-defined) to get

$$n(\ln(n-x) - \ln(n+x)) < -2x$$

To prove the above inequality, let $a(x) = n(\ln(n-x) - \ln(n+x))$. I will now show that $a'(x) < -2$ for $x \in (0,n)$ which is enough to prove the above. Computing the derivative gives

$$a'(x) = -2 \left(\frac{n^2}{n^2-x^2}\right) < -2 \left(\frac{n^2-x^2}{n^2-x^2}\right) = -2.$$

Comment: If it is easier to understand visually, [look here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/aszl2lz68q).

Comment: That was what I had I mind with my comment. Well done!